# svn: renaming feature branch in mid of development

Tags: svn, branch, branching-and-merging

Have next situation:

trunk branched at rev X -> branches/br1

... dev with periodical synch trunk -> br1

br1 renamed to br2 (at this moment br1 was not completely synched with trunk)

... dev with periodical synch trunk -> br2

finally br2 was synchronized with trunk. Try reintegrate from br2 to trunk, but TortoiseSVN show error like this:

```
Command: Reintegrate merge .../branches/br2 into ...wc\trunk
Error: Reintegrate can only be used if revisions 12306 through 13012 were previously
Error:  merged from .../trunk to the   
Error:  reintegrate source, but this is not the case:   
Error:   branches/br2/prj1   
Error:     Missing ranges: /trunk/prj1:12359-12728
Error:   branches/br2/prj2   
Error:     Missing ranges: /trunk/prj2:12847   
Completed!
```

Seems rename branch was bad idea :(

So, how this situation can be resolved? Make reintegrate br1 and then br2? But currently br1 (deleted) not synchronyzed with trunk and far from it.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, answer was found after 0.5 hous after ask question...

The problem was in additional svn:mergeinfo of several paths in br2
(nothing with branch rename...)

```
svn propdel svn:mergeinfo -R .
svn revert .
```

solves problem.